# syntax error in UPDATE statement vb.net/ MS access 2007

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2007, vb.net-2010

Im trying to update a table after i insert a new record on other table but im having a error message (syntax error in update statement) everytime it runs the code after succesfully adding a record. Im using MS ACCESS 2007 as my database heres my code:

Thank you in advace

```
Public Sub addnew()
    Dim add As String = String.Empty
    add &= "insert into output_tbl(assycde,model_id,unit_serial,barcoded_serial_qty,Time_stamp,plan_id)"
    add &= " values "
    add &= "('" & cmbassycode.Text & "','" & txtmodel.Text & "','" & txtunitserial.Text & "','" & txtbs.Text & "','" & dtimestamp.Text & "','" & txtplanid.Text & "');"
    Dim connection1 As String = ("provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\\tepisql02\System\ProdSched\planning.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;")
    Using conn1 As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(connection1)
        Using cmd1 As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(add)
            With cmd1
                .Connection = conn1
                .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                .CommandText = add
            End With
            Try
                conn1.Open()
                If cmbassycode.Text = "" Then
                    MsgBox("Please Select A Assycode")
                End If

                cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
                MsgBox("New Output Succesfuly Added")



                Dim int As Integer = 1
                Integer.TryParse(txtbs.Text, int)
                txtbs.Text = (int + 1)
                txtunitserial.Clear()


                conn1.Close()
                'End If   
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message)
            End Try

        End Using
    End Using

    Dim countbar As String = DataGridView1.RowCount + 1
    Dim updcountactive As String = String.Empty
    updcountactive &= "Update setplan set Count=" & countbar & " , Actual='" & dtimestamp.Text & "' "
    updcountactive &= "where ID=" & txtplanid.Text & ";"
    MsgBox(updcountactive)
    Dim connection2 As String = ("provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\\tepisql02\System\ProdSched\planning.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;")
    Using conn2 As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(connection2)
        Using cmd2 As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(updcountactive)
            With cmd2
                .Connection = conn2
                .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                .CommandText = updcountactive
            End With
            Try
                conn2.Open()
                cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()
                conn2.Close()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message)
            End Try
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm always amazed that this has to be stated but if the error message tells you that there's a syntax error in your `UPDATE` statement then the obvious first thing to do should be to look at your `UPDATE` statement. The code that creates that `UPDATE` statement is of secondary interest. Look at your `UPDATE` statement first. If you still can't see the issue, show it to us.

Comment: Having said that, issues like this are often the result of using string concatenation to build SQL code and not thinking about all the possibilities. If you use parameters with your ADO.NET code then a whole host of possible SQL syntax errors just go away, as well as the more important possibility of SQL injection.  You should learn how to use parameters in ADO.NET immediately and implement it in this code. [Here](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com.au/2009/08/using-parameters-in-adonet.html) is some useful information on that subject.

Comment: You have opened a connection and then displayed a message box. What if the user went to a meeting. There sits your open connection.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps!

'updcountactive &= "where ID=" & txtplanid.Text & ";"'

"txtplanid.Text" this return a string value, 
Is the ID Field is integer in table then its not works

updcountactive &= "where ID=" & convert.int32(txtplanid.Text) & "